# Flex keeps on resizing itself in Firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using Vis.js to create diagrams. Relevant code:

```css
.defaultSection {
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
}

.overflowHidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.flexParent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 2px;
}

.flexParentInvisible {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexElement {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.flexPanel {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.roundedCorners {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div data-panes="true">
  <div id="Tab-ta6f7ijb-Content" class="active">
    <div class="defaultSection roundedCorners overflowHidden">
      <div class="defaultHeader" style="text-align:center;background-color:#00bfff"><a name="Test" style="color: #ffffff;">Test </a><a id="show_505656775" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('505656775');" style="color: #ffffff; display:none;">(Show)</a><a id="hide_505656775" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="hide('505656775');"
          style="color: #ffffff; display:none;">(Hide)</a></div>
      <div id="505656775" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden">
        <div id="505656775" class="flexParent flexElement overflowHidden collapsable">
          <div id="Diagram-hvardq4p" class="diagram"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Full code: https://codepen.io/MadBoyEvo/pen/XWmbZra

It works fine in Chrome, Edge, IE and even Firefox with one problem. In firefox, the section where diagram is located keeps on resizing itself over and over. I'm sure this is my mistake with CSS but whatever I try to fix it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Author of Vis.js provided me with a tip: https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/628

```html
<div Class="diagram" Style="position:relative">
     <div style="position:absolute" id="Diagram-w5gcskfb" class="diagram"></div>
</div>
```

This solves it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is contained in a `<canvas>` element. That element has two `height` values assigned, both as inline styles:

- `height: 100%`, and
- `height="484"` (or whatever value it happens to have at the moment).

Once you remove the `height: 100%` the rolling expansion stops.

[image]

Comment: I see that but I have no way to remove it from code that I manage as far as I can see?

Comment: If there's a way for you to load `height: auto` to the CSS right after the program loads, it can work. But it doesn't seem to work if it's loaded with the rest of the code. https://codepen.io/mbb7774/pen/mdeEbLj

Comment: I'll ask the owner of vis.js if he thinks this is an error on his side or still should be fixed on my end. Thank you

Comment: It may also be a glitch in Firefox, since it's working on the other browsers. Good luck.